# I'm trying to update an existing user but it keeps creating a new user, how do I go about this?

Tags: spring-mvc

[my User controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hx90t.png)

[my service implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r45y4.png)

Comment: Add code as text not as image.

Answer (score 0):

In the `UserServiceImpl`, `updateUsers` function, do a `findbyId` or `findbyuser` to get the ID of the user.

Check if that user is already present and then call the save function within that if.

Sample:

```
Do a isuserexisting = repository. findbyid or findbyUser
if(isuserexisting != null) 
response.setId(isuserexisting.getId());
usersRepository.save(response);
```

Comment: thanks for your help

Comment: Is that first line supposed to be in the code block?

Comment: Yes Jeremy Caney.